# Problem with getting the input button to hover and fuse with the input text

Tags: html, css, input

I've tried my best to fuse my **input button** and the **icon** I got from the net together.... And also put it together with my **input text** tag as well...

If you look closely at the images below,the button on my page is the orange box between the icon and the input text.

Plus it's refusing to hover

Please, can someone check to see what I'm doing wrong and offer some help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> TO DO LIST</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Project.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>Ak's To Do List</h1>
</header>
<form>
    <input type="text" class="todo-input">
    <button class="todo-button" type="submit"></button>
    <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
</form>

<div class="todo-container">
<ul class="todo-list">
    <div class="todo"></ul>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Project.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365, #fda085);
    color: white;
    font-family: "Indie Flower", sans-serif;
    min-height:100vh;
}

header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

header,
form{
    min-height:20vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

form input, 
form button{
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    border:none;
    background: white;
}

form button{
    color: #fda085;
    background: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:  all 0.3s ease;
}

form button{
    background: #fda085;
    color: white;
}
```

[image: My Todo page]
What I am getting

[image: How it's supposed to be]
How it is supposed to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon `<i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>` can be placed inside the button:

```
<button class="todo-button" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></button>
```

This will give you the effect you are looking for.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365, #fda085);
    color: white;
    font-family: "Indie Flower", sans-serif;
    min-height:100vh;
}

header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

header,
form{
    min-height:20vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

form input, 
form button{
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    border:none;
    background: white;
}

form button{
    color: #fda085;
}

form button:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> TO DO LIST</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Project.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>Ak's To Do List</h1>
</header>
<form>
    <input type="text" class="todo-input">
    <button class="todo-button" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></button>
</form>

<div class="todo-container">
<ul class="todo-list">
    <div class="todo"></ul>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Project.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For the hover effect, you need to create a new style definition using the `:hover` pseudo-element as shown below. I included that in the snippet above.

```
form button:hover {
      color: green;
    }
```

See here for more about `:hover`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Comment: Exactly what I needed... Thank you so much @Rob Moll